# What are the differences between OVF-Version 0.9, 1.0 and 2.0?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, export

I have Virtualbox 4.3 and want to export different VMs because I'm recover my computer. When I want to export a VM I can choose between OVF-Format-Version 0.9; 1.0; 2.0

But what are the differences between them? How do I decide which one to use?

I also want to export the saved state from the VMs.

Comment: I would select the highest version you need to be compatible with.  If you're only ever going to import from the same software that created the export, use the highest.

Comment: The [Open Virtualization Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Virtualization_Format), which is a format that many different VM platforms can use to import VMs.

Comment: As of Virtualbox 5.0.24 (32 bit, Win) , Virtualbox mentions that OVF 2.0 is experimental when you hover the mouse over the Format Select field.

Answer (score 39):

Extract from the [OVF 2.0 FAQ](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/DMTF_OVF_2%200_FAQ__Final_1.pdf):

> **What are the new improvements/features of OVF 2.0 vs. OVF 1.0?**
>
> OVF 1.0 has provided the industry with a standard packaging format for
>   virtual machines – solving a critical business need for software
>   vendors and cloud service providers. OVF 1.0 has been widely adopted
>   to meet this need and is now an international standard (adopted by
>   ISO/IEC in 2011).
>
> OVF 2.0 brings an enhanced set of capabilities to the packaging of
>   virtual machines, making the standard applicable to a broader range of
>   cloud use cases that are emerging as the industry enters the cloud
>   era. The most significant improvements include support for network
>   configuration along with the ability to encrypt the package to ensure
>   safe delivery.
>
> New features of OVF 2.0 include:
>
> - Improved support for network configuration
> - Package encryption for safe delivery
> - Scaling and deployment options
> - Support for basic placement policies, including affinity and availability placement
> - Shared disks
> - Advanced device boot order
> - Advanced mechanisms for passing data to guest
> - Updated CIM schemas

Comment: OVF 2.0 FAQ link to non-pdf html document (same site): https://www.dmtf.org/about/faq/ovf_faq

Comment: OVF 2.0 FAQ link to non-pdf html document (same site): https://www.dmtf.org/about/faq/ovf_faq

Answer (score -3):

My suggestion is to go with version 1.0 or 2.0 since OVF Tool 2.0 supports OVF version 1.0 and 1.1, and is backward compatible with OVF 0.9.